# How can I adjust the cursor size or reset it to the default value?

Tags: 11.10, cursor

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I change the cursor and its size?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/126491/how-do-i-change-the-cursor-and-its-size)

I don't know why, but after installing Ubuntu 11.10 the cursors are **very** large. Not always but almost in all applications (See the screenshot below.)

[image]

How can I adjust the cursor size or reset it to the default value?