# Huge mouse cursor arrow after installing Nvidia drivers

Tags: nvidia, cursor

After installing the proprietary Nvidia drivers, my mouse cursor looks like this:

[image: Large mouse pointer]

The arrow image is much larger than normal. How can I fix it?

### Details

- How I installed the Nvidia drivers:

  1. Install `linux-source`, `linux-headers-generic`, and `nvidia-current-updates`, then reboot.
  2. Run `sudo nvidia-xconfig`.
  3. Run `gksudo nvidia-settings`, adjust the absolute position of my two monitors, and save the automatically generated `xorg.conf`.
  4. Apply the [workaround](https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity/+bug/1057000/comments/37) for [bug #1057000](https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity/+bug/1057000) to [`xorg.conf`](http://paste.ubuntu.com/1421994/), then reboot.
- The cursor size settings referred to in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/126511/1859) are [normal](http://paste.ubuntu.com/1422023/).
- The problem does not happen when the mouse pointer is over Amarok or Firefox.

Comment: I did a fresh installation of Ubuntu 13.04 for other reasons and can't reproduce this anymore.

Comment: I have this problem.

Comment: @Greg Go ahead and open a new question with the details of your setup, and just be sure to link to this one.

Comment: Same problem with amd drivers.. Fix below does not work.

Comment: for me, i got huge cursor in ubuntu after a reboot using open source drivers (intel) and i fixed it by editing ~/.Xresources or ~/.Xdefaults and adding this line : ```Xcursor.size: 12``` and then execute ```xrdb ~/.Xresources``` (or ~/.Xdefaults). New application should be fixed, to apply to all, restart X

Answer (score 4):

I got the same problem and in the end, I just switched from `lightdm` to `gdm` and that fixed it.

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm
```

then reboot.

Comment: I too had this problem and a ``sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm`` then log out and in fixed it for me.

Comment: I don't think this problem really justifies switching to a nonstandard display manager. Also, @codeape, that should be posted as a separate answer. And no, it didn't resolve the problem for me.

Comment: I had this issue in Debian 8.5 and switching to gdm3 worked.