# How do I obtain and install larger mouse pointers - I am slightly visually impaired

Tags: cursor

I am totally new to Ubuntu. Just this morning (Wed May 22, 2013) I installed Ubuntu 12.04.2 64-bit desktop on my 2.5 year old laptop along side Windows 7. One of the reasons I installed Ubuntu was to explore and employ the Universal Access options - I have some vision impairment. So far so good. However I need larger mouse pointers. The default is microscopically small, to me, and I have searched and searched Ask Ubuntu, The Software Center, etc. for a way to get a larger mouse pointer (this is very easy in Windows 7). As a new user I would prefer to avoid command lines and configuration editors and do a simple install, as I would in Windows 7.

How do I obtain and install a set of larger mouse pointers?

Thank you very much for your attention to this question.

and when I try "For GNOME classic and Unity desktop the option to change the mouse pointer size or style is found in System Settings -> Appearance -> Theme -> Customize -> Pointer:" there is NO 'customize.' There are only 4 themes to choose from.

I have looked at the "Questions that might already have your answer" and, come on, Ubuntu says it is easy for the disabled but following all these "nightmarish" procedures by a visually impaired person is a bit much to ask.

Sorry if I am coming across as lazy or stupid but after a while staring at these screens my eyes give out altogether ...

Comment: [Not the GUI option you were searching but seems to work](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Yxfa2fXJ1Wc). Maybe someone else could type it up as a proper answer?

Answer (score 8):

If you prefer GUI you can use `unity-tweak-tool`.

**How to:**

Open Ubuntu Software Center, search for `unity-tweak-tool` and install it.

Open `unity-tweak-tool`. Under `Appearance`, click on `Cursor`:

[image]

Under `Preferences` enable ☑ `Use large cursors`:

[image]

Logout and log back in.

**Custom Cursor Themes:**

If you don't like the default cursors you can download a nice, large cursor theme from [here](http://gnome-look.org/content/show.php/Large+Mouse+Cursors?content=140787).

Extract the downloaded archive to `.icons` directory in your `home`, create `.icons` directory if it doesn't already exist.

Open `unity-tweak-too` and go to cursor settings as described earlier and select `Large mouse cursors`:

[image]
Logout and log back in.

Answer (score 3):

open a terminal window [ CTRL+ALT+T ] and type in the following commands (alternatively you can use dconf-editor from the package dconf-tools)

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface cursor-size 48
```

then

```
gedit ~/.Xresources
```

so paste the following line and save the file

```
Xcursor.size: 48
```

you have to change 48 with your desired value, the default is 24

Answer (score 0):

I did a little research and it appears that there is a package named dconf-editor available from universe source. Check out [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/126491/how-do-i-change-the-cursor-and-its-size) question for details. It appears to be quite easy and it doesn't involve any CLI commands - it's purely graphical.

Answer (score -1):

as in answer 1, Type `CTRL F` (find) and in the search box (Bottom Left) type in **Cursor** and hit Enter.

**Cursor size** is the fourth option from the top. 24 is normal, increase it to any size you want, (try 54) it works instantly.

For some reason, for me, this only increases the size of the cursor on some applications, but it may help