# Mouse cursor size behaviour in Gnome Shell?

Tags: gnome, mouse, cursor

In Gnome Shell, it looks like the mouse cursor is scaled to nearly 1.5x it's usual size to what looks like a "novelty".

Moving the cursor over a "non Gnome" application such as Google Chrome, makes the cursor the "right size".

I have installed Ubuntu 16.04 with the "ubuntu-desktop" option and afterwards installed the gnome-shell, which I am using as my window manager. I've been doing this for years across many Ubuntu releases (including LTS) and now on 16.04 and this has always bothered me.

Therefore, I was wondering if anyone else has seen this, or have any ideas how to solve it?

When capturing the mouse cursor with different screenshot utilities, they all showed up the correct size. So here comes two actual photos of the screen for comparison:

Large cursor:

[image: Large cursor]

Normal cursor:

[image: Normal cursor]

Comment: Is your screenshot from same zoom settings? I see that your picture is pixelated. Why?

Comment: @kennetho Did you find any solutions for this ?

Answer (score 2):

I have the opposite problem. I want a large cursor, and made it so, but non gnome apps make it smaller again!

In mint 17, I use the following.

```
gsettings set org.cinnamon.desktop.interface cursor-size 40
```

Try gsettings in ubuntu. See [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/744833/581607)

For me (mint), the change happens straight away and is retained on reboots. However, there was mention of it reverting on ubuntu upon a restart.

Answer (score 2):

Had the same problem, the following fix from [here](https://github.com/regolith-linux/regolith-desktop/issues/417#issuecomment-822237858) worked for me in gnome (change the numeric value to whatever your default is)

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface cursor-size 12
```