# Why mouse pointer showing as a square on desktop?

Tags: server, gnome, mouse

Just installed Ubuntu server 22.04 and as I needed a DE, followed some tutorials where most of them suggested that I can install gnome (or ubuntu-desktop) using the `tasksel` command.

After doing so I encountered two problems:
the mouse pointer on desktop is showing as a solid gray square ⬛ and the hotspot is at upper left corner. However when I run any gui app the pointer is drawn perfectly fine.

How can I fix this issues?

Comment: Please focus to one question at a time on this site.

Comment: If you "need a DE" why didn't you install the desktop version instead?

Comment: @ChanganAuto for learning purposes

Comment: @vanadium sure, edited my question.

Comment: "Ubuntu server" lacks the GUI components and services that your DE depends on. Start over, and install "Ubuntu desktop", since you want to use your computer as a desktop.Telling us which remote procedure (RP) you "followed" doesn't help us help you for N reasons: 1) It's remote. Will the link exist tomorrow? 2) Reading  the RP doesn't tell us how accurately you "followed" it. Did you suffer typos or missed lines? We have. 3) Reading the RP omits the error messages **you** got on **your system**. These error messages (and the commands that caused them) are key elements in any diagnosis.

Comment: @waltinator if I wanted to install the desktop version, obviously wouldn't proceeded to download the server in the first place. I'm sure it's possible to add gui to the server and looking for some help regarding that. About the error messages I know I need to provide those but didn't encounter any.

Comment: I actually have this issue on desktop. :-)

Comment: I do think it is a legitimate question. I have just finished installing two very old laptops, and have the same problem on both. I used the server image to have a basic installation because old, resource constrained hardware, and added what is needed. I think it is a legit expectation to have the same behaviour with the same packages installed, and having a square instead of mouse pointer - while not a big deal - is annoying.

Answer (score 2):

If inside the VirtualBox VM, and with the latest kernel 6.5.*, it is necessary to install the newer compiler:

```
sudo apt install gcc-12
```

After that, it is necessary to install the latest Guest Additions.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that changing the cursor theme works: [How do I change the cursor and its size?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/126491/how-do-i-change-the-cursor-and-its-size)

```
apt install oxygen-cursor-theme
update-alternatives --config x-cursor-theme
```

Answer (score 0):

What solved it for me was going into the Menu -> "Tweaks" -> "Appareance" and set Cursor to one of the options in the blank dropdown. In my case, "DMZ Black".

Note that this requires the `ubuntu-desktop` install using tasksel. The minimal one doesn't ome with "Tweaks" afaik.